# How to replace single and double quotes with escape sequences (for string passed to strtok)

Tags: c, escaping, quotes, strtok

I'm trying to replace single and double quotes with their escaped versions in a char array. I'm doing this because `strtok` isn't parsing past single/double quotes when it hits them.

I wrote the following function to try to replace single/double quotes in a char array:

```
void replaceQuotes(char *command){
int i;

for(i = 0; i < strlen(command); i++){
    //if detected a double quote, escape it
    if(command[i] == '\"'){
        command[i] = '\\\"';
    }
    // if detected a single quote, escape it
    if (command[i] == '\''){
        command[i] = '\\\'';
    }
}
```

}

However, I'm getting the following errors from `gcc`:

```
shell_lib.h: In function ‘replaceQuotes’:
shell_lib.h:10: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion
shell_lib.h:14:17: warning: multi-character character constant
shell_lib.h:14: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this? Actually, I'm not sure if this is even effective or if strtok will actually read the escape sequences (if I were able to escape them) correctly as a single/double quote. Suggestions on other ways to deal with strtok returning `NULL` when it hits a double/single quote are also appreciated!

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: What you are doing is replacing a single character with 2 characters. What are your delimiters for `strtok`?

Comment: I'm delimiting using a whitespace, i.e. `" "`. Yeah I had that suspicion, but thought maybe since the escape characters are for escaping within my source file, it might compile to just one character. Which probably doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
'\\\''
```

this is for refering to a signle character.  But you are trying to put two characters in there.  You can't do that.

If you were trying to escape your string you'd have to create a new one ( or move things in the current one ) to insert extra characters.

However, it sounds like your REAL problem is what you were trying to do with strtok, which should work fine without any escaping needed in the string your a strtoking.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks for confirming both those things. I'll do a little more debugging first